# get everything after a directory name from filepath

Tags: php, path, directory

The directory name is : `files`

And my filepath looks like : `C:/MAMP/htdocs/files/Rbiaali/Assassins-Creed-Revelations-400x400.jpg`

Now what i just want is to get everything after the `files` directory, that should be:

```
Rbiaali/Assassins-Creed-Revelations-400x400.jpg
```

**NOTE**

The filepath can start from different paths but it will always contain `files`

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL no i have a downloader that  requires full path thus i cant just strip it out

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL also the file can be in subfolders too inside the root folder

Comment: in the example above the folder `Rbiaali` can also contain subfolder and file inside that subfolder.Thus i need the path after `files` Please answer if have any solution.

Comment: i need to show the user the path to the file but just from its username i.e in the example `Rbiaali`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "C:/MAMP/htdocs/files/Rbiaali/Assassins-Creed-Revelations-400x400.jpg";
$needle="files/";
echo substr($str, strpos($str,$needle)+strlen($needle));
```

Comment: ahh let me check

Comment: this is giving `MP/htdocs/files/Rbiaali/Assassins-Creed-Revelations-400x400.jpg `

Comment: There has to be something that reads according to the slash `/`